# NameError in RailsAdmin::Main#index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, rails-admin

> I'm using **rails_admin** along with the **devise** gem, looks like everything is working fine with dashboard but whenever I switch to **user** it throw *uninitialized constant User::Authentication raise NameError. new("uninitialized constant #{candidates.first}", candidates.first)* error. https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWOP4.png This is my error screenshot. Any help will be appreciated.
>   Below is my **user.rb** file,

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
 # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
 # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
 devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

 has_many :posts
 has_many :comments
 has_many :authentications
end
```

Comment: Do you have a "candidate" model ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have "candidate" model. @bTazi

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with this today while trying to namespace a model, and found that the basic search filters were to blame;

The problem was resolved as soon as I added a new filter; I'd say it's because adding a new filter removed the basic filters that created the issue... (here is an explanation on how to do it : https://activeadmin.info/3-index-pages.html)

I hope this will be useful.